# Expected struct Config, found () while using process::exit

Tags: error-handling, rust, closures, traits

I'm new to Rust and going through the official book. I'm working on a simple grep example and want to make an `exit` function which I can use in different places. Unfortunately using this function in a closure in `unwrap_or_else` causes a compile error. This not clear to me why, because when I use the contents of the function directly in the closure it works.

Here is my `main.rs` file:

```
use std::env;
use std::fs;
use std::process;
use std::error::Error;
use std::fmt::Display;

struct Config{
    query: String,
    filename: String,
}

impl Config {
    fn new(input: &[String]) -> Result<Config, &'static str> {
        if input.len() < 3 {
            return Err("Not enough arguments provided.");
        }
        let query = input[1].clone();
        let filename = input[2].clone();

        Ok(Config { query, filename })
    }
}

fn run(cfg: Config) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let contents = fs::read_to_string(&cfg.filename)?;
    contents.find(&cfg.query).expect("Corrupted text file.");

    Ok(())
}

fn exit<T: Display>(msg: &str, err: T) {
    println!("{}: {}", msg, err);
    process::exit(1);
}

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    println!("{:?}", args);

    let cfg = Config::new(&args).unwrap_or_else(|err| {
        exit("Problem parsing arguments", err);
    });
    
    if let Err(err) = run(cfg) {
        exit("Application error", err);
    }
}
```

And here is the compile error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\main.rs:41:55
   |
41 |       let cfg = Config::new(&args).unwrap_or_else(|err| {
   |  _______________________________________________________^
42 | |         exit("Problem parsing arguments", err);
43 | |     });
   | |_____^ expected struct `Config`, found `()`
```

When I change the `Config::new(&args).unwrap_or_else` closure to this, it works:

```
let cfg = Config::new(&args).unwrap_or_else(|err| {
    println!("Problem parsing arguments: {}", err);
    process::exit(1);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify, that your `exit()` function never returns, i.e. add `-> !`.

These functions are called "[diverging functions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/fn/diverging.html)".

```rust
fn exit<T: Display>(msg: &str, err: T) -> ! {
    println!("{}: {}", msg, err);
    process::exit(1);
}
```

However, you should be careful with using [`process::exit()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/fn.exit.html). Because it will terminate the current process, and **not invoke destructors.**

To ensure destructors are handled, you should instead do something like this:

```
fn main() {
    std::process::exit(match run() {
        Ok(_) => 0,
        Err(code) => code,
    });
}

fn run() -> Result<(), i32> {
    // Application logic here, i.e. what you'd otherwise have had in `main()`

    Ok(())
}
```

*The example is a minor adapted version of the one found at the documentation for [`process::exit()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/fn.exit.html).*

Comment: @mcarton The point about destructors is a good one, I've updated the answer to include that :)

Comment: @vallentin Now I'm happy :)

Comment: [Here's an idea for restoring the custom error messages](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f24435fd37c53068ba16d45d500da206). Although in a well-designed program the error type's `Display` implementation should probably take care of that, [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0ac59340bbb4d55cfd3c264c7c90a2f1).

Comment: There's also something like "[Custom Exit Status Codes with ? in main](https://www.joshmcguigan.com/blog/custom-exit-status-codes-rust/)". However, it uses the [`std::process::Termination`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/trait.Termination.html) trait which is nightly-only.

Answer (score 5):

I got stuck on this too. You need to import the process library:

```
use std::process;
```

edit: On second look you did import it. For others who run into this problem then that was mine. I got the same error.

Comment: This was the fix I needed for the tutorial at https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch12-03-improving-error-handling-and-modularity.html

Answer (score 3):

To add to [vallentin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65980166/2766908) here's the more idiomatic version which doesn't use `process::exit`:

```rust
use std::env;
use std::error::Error;
use std::fmt::Display;
use std::fs;
use std::process;

struct Config {
    query: String,
    filename: String,
}

impl Config {
    fn new(input: &[String]) -> Result<Config, &'static str> {
        if input.len() < 3 {
            return Err("Not enough arguments provided.");
        }
        let query = input[1].clone();
        let filename = input[2].clone();

        Ok(Config { query, filename })
    }
}

fn run(cfg: Config) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let contents = fs::read_to_string(&cfg.filename)?;
    // convert Option to a Result so we can use `?`
    contents.find(&cfg.query).ok_or("Corrupted text file.")?;
    Ok(())
}

// you can return a Result from main and Rust will
// print the error to the user if there is one
fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    println!("{:?}", args);

    // use `?` instead of `exit` function
    let cfg = Config::new(&args)?;
    run(cfg)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e8d8b696b9825940c8d774e15dd4ec13)